How to prevent debug and release configurations generating contradictory errors for 'unreachable code' and 'not all paths return a value'
Please see the code example below

Does anyone know why visual studio 22 behaves this way
Does anyone know if there is a setting or something i can change to my debug configuration so that it does not generate the 'not all paths return a value' warning

Note: I have 'treat warnings as errors' - this cannot change
// In debug this compiles
// In release this has a compiler warning about unreachable code
int aaa()
{
  int value = 0;
  try
  {
    value = myFunctionThatCouldThrow();
  }
  catch (const std::exception& exc)
  {
    ThisFunctionALWAYSThrows(exc);
  }
  return value;
}

// In debug this has a compiler warning that not all paths return a value
// In release this compiles
int aaa()
{
  try
  {
    return myFunctionThatCouldThrow();
  }
  catch (const std::exception& exc)
  {
    ThisFunctionALWAYSThrows(exc);
  }
}

// This compiles in both but requires the preprocessor debug flag
int aaa()
{
  try
  {
    return myFunctionThatCouldThrow();
  }
  catch (const std::exception& exc)
  {
    ThisFunctionALWAYSThrows(exc);
  }
#ifdef _DEBUG
  // The return statement is a pointless line as it can never be hit - I agree with the release build warning
  // yet without this return statement - code building in debug generates a warning...
  // I know I could also pragma ignore the warning - Im hoping for a cleaner solution without macros
  // There are multiple functions in the code base that behave this way (the codes been ported from VS17)
  // A non macro solution is better as I dont need to amend all functions
  // I also dont want a more global ignore of the warning as that could hide genuine issues
  return -1;
#endif
}


Do you have exceptions disabled in debug build by any chance? Or is myFunctionThatCouldThrow potentially throwing something that is not std::exception?

This is the classic example of why turning warnings into errors is a bad idea. The compiler does different levels of analysis with different settings. You've chosen to turn legal code into illegal code at the compiler's whim, and this is one of the consequences. It's not the compiler's job to determine whether your code is correct. It's your job, and you have to take charge.

@PeteBecker you can't do that in a corporate setting, everyone will ignore all warnings if they don't turn into errors, instead you can disable a specific warning for a specific part of code if you know that the compiler is hallucinating.

In debug mode you can sometimes get away with (incorrect) things that will sort of work but may then be optimised in a release build in a way that is wrong. Paths that do not return a value is one such. It is worth making sure all paths do return a value.  Unreachable code warnings should not be ignored for the same reason (the compiler dataflow analysis is usually right on them - ie it is a latent bug).

#ifdef _DEBUG is Microsoft-specific. A standard-compliant way is #ifndef NGEBUG.

To clarify - the situation here is that myFunctionThatCouldThrow() actually always throws?  And I suppose that in release, the compiler knows this (e.g. because it inlines it) but in debug mode it does not.

@AhmedAEK -- being in a "corporate4 setting" (whatever that means...) doesn't automatically mean having a bad development process. Going along with it won't fix it. And, yes, if "everyone will ignore all warnings" you've got a broken development process, with fundamental problems that have to be dealt with.

if it throws another exception type - it still cant reach the return statement - as its thrown and not been caught

@PeteBecker there are pros and cons turning warnings into errors - one such pro is that it will force a developer to fix any warnings they create - allowing warnings to be ignored could end up with serious issues - by turning them into errors it forces a dev to decide themselves whether that warning can safely be ignored. In this case i can safely ignore this warning - but id rather not as its a lot of donkey work to add all the pragmas in

@NateEldredge Its in the name - the function could throw - equally it might not - it depends on the input to the function - my example code is dumbed down considerably so has omitted any input values - i didn't think it would be relevant

@Danaldo -- not turning on "treat all warnings an errors" is not equivalent to "allowing warnings to be ignored". The first is about enforcement; there are other ways to address warnings.

So then you're saying the warnings are simply wrong?  In version 1, the return is reachable if the function doesn't throw.  And in version 2, all paths do return a value.

@PeteBecker I agree - they are not equivalent - however treat warnings as errors does provide a mechanism to ensure they are not ignored as the code will not compile. I guess this is a philosophical aspect of coding. Whether I prefer one way or another doesnt matter if its a corporate policy

@NateEldredge at compile time it cannot be determined that the function will throw - at runtime it depends on the function inputs an example of such is parsing a value from a file. Whats plain odd is how the release compiler complains about unreachable code - whereas the debug compiler will complain about not all paths returning a value.

@Yksisarvinen Which setting are you referring to? The only one I can think of is under 'Debug->Windows->Exception Settings' However this only controls what happens on a throw when running - not when it compiles... Is there another setting that effects compilation?

Ok - so just discussing this has been helpful - thankyou - I've worked out the issue - I will post an answer on monday that explains what was happening in case anyone else encounters this.

Yes, that is odd.  So I would suggest taking another very careful look at the function.  Everything you're saying is consistent with the compiler having determined that the function must throw, so if that's not true, then you're basically claiming the compiler is buggy - which is possible, but only to be considered when you have truly ruled out other options.  See also "It's always your fault"

In general, I turn warnings into errors, and I rarely disable warnings in the code (unless it's before including a buggy third-party header) -- instead, I just fix them. If the compiler complains about a variable being used uninitialized because it can't see that this is wrong, I just initialize it. If the compiler complains about a path not returning value, even if it's unreachable anyway, I return a value. If a smarter compiler can handle these cases, they will also be able to optimize my unnecessary stuff away, like an unnecessary initialization or an unreachable return.

First up apologies - my initial code was not going to reproduce the issue - it was copied from code i couldnt share as an example. Its amended now. The questions posted did assist me in spotting this oversight and working out the error. Thankyou.
Onto the answer - its just due to the optimiser. The function that always throws is optimised to be an inline throw meaning release wont complain about all paths not returning a value. Whereas debug it wont optimise and it will complain.

First thing I need to mention that I couldn't reproduce your warnings in Compiler Explorer with any available MSVC compilers. Try providing reproducible example.
Assuming that the warning really exists, you can disable it with #pragma warning(disable: 4702), where 4702 is the unreachable code warning.
Notice, that when using warnings with numbers 4700-4999 a special rule exists. Quoting from Microsoft documentation: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-170)

Warning numbers in the range 4700-4999 are associated with code
generation. For these warnings, the state of the warning in effect
when the compiler reaches the function definition remains in effect
for the rest of the function. Use of the warning pragma in the
function to change the state of a warning number larger than 4699 only
takes effect after the end of the function.

In your case it would look like this:
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4702)
// In debug this compiles
// In release this has a compiler warning about unreachable code
int aaa()
{
  int value = 0;
  try
  {
    value = myFunctionThatCouldThrow();
  }
  catch (const std::exception& exc)
  {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "my function threw: " << exc.what();
    throw std::runtime_error(ss.str().c_str());
  }
  return value;
  #pragma warning(pop)
}


As a matter of style, if you push before a function, you should pop after the function, not inside the function.

@Dúthomhas -- that's not a matter of style. I quoted Microsoft documentation that explains why you need to do it inside the function.

You have misunderstood the docs. They make it clear that you cannot change the state inside the function; any change must be made before the function. Hence, wrap the function with the push, set, and pop pragmas. Don’t do some weird intermix inside the function.

@Gene - although they give an example that does exactly that without saying why I suspect this is a fairly typical Microsoft unhelpful bad coding example rather than something you should aspire to doing. Putting both push and pop outside the routine should be correct. Putting pop inside the routine is as ugly as hell even if it works.

@Duthomas Gene is right that MS do say that is what you should do (and give an example with that ugly style) but don't say why. It looks like bad advice to me. YMMV
